# Retrieve quickly varbinary/image data from database,

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, image, varbinary, varbinarymax

I have more over 10000 (varbinary/image) entries in a SQL Server table and I want to retrieve/fetch all that data immediately. Is it possible? I am using ASP.NET as my front end. If I use data table, I list etc methods its takes at least 2 to 3 minutes.

Purpose Finger Print attendance maintain system (ZkTecko device), frontend ASP.NET windows application.

Comment: Network might be fast, but they still take time to move data.

Comment: Is any other solution? because we are took all data from database and match with appropriate finger from device

Comment: Seems to me it would be quicker to pass the single image from the device to the server and match it there?

Comment: I already tried that ways , but i couldn't get proper result,The Finger print device match with some algorithms , its have appropriate DLL files ,

Comment: I'm sure it can work... just need to fix your issue. Transferring 10,000 images to the client sounds very wrong. And will always take some time.

Comment: But i tried , if i register 1 finger template using device , next time same finger template getting another value using var Binary

Comment: You'd need to open a new question and provide a lot more information in order for anyone to be able to help you. The answer to this question is, no, to transfer a large amount of image data will always take time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve the performance you could do following steps:

1) You should save the image path in the image field in the database and upload image to server instead of storing image in database. Because image size is usually large it takes more storage and takes time to fetch data.

2) Secondly you should use `pagination` at frontend or database end instead of fetching all the record at once. This approach will also improve the performance of your system.

I would recommend if you use datatable with the pagination at database end.